# A question about the Integral of an odd function with respect to a finite measure.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on borelians of $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\mu(\mathbb R^2)< \infty$. Let $R = [-r,r]\times [-r,r]$, with $r>0$, and $Q = \mathbb R^2 \setminus R$.

How to show that:
$$\int_Q \frac{x}{\|x\|^2} d \mu(x)=0.\label{I}\tag{I}$$
First, I don't think **(I)** is true for any measure $\mu$. So I would like to know for what measures we have that **(I)** is true?

For example, if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, I think that it is possible to conclude that **(I)**  is true. For the univariate case, we trivially have that:
$$\int_{|x|\geq r} \frac{x}{|x|^2}  dx = 0,$$
since $g(x)=\frac{x}{|x|^2}$ an odd function and the region of integration is symmetric. So this leads me to suspect that perhaps **(I)** is true if the measure $d\mu(x)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure (i.e., if $d\mu(x)$ is of the form $ f(x)dx$ for some function $f(x)$. But then, we would have to analyze the properties of $f$.

Help!

Comment: If $d\mu (x)=f(x)dx$ and $f$ is an even function then $\int g(x)d\mu(x)=0$ for every odd function $g$.

Comment: Typo in the definition of $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu (-E)=\mu (E)$ for every Borel set $E$, then $\int g(x)d\mu(x)=0$ for every odd function $g$. Lebesgue measure has this property.

Suppose $\mu (-E)=\mu (E)$ for every Borel set $E$. Let $g$ be any non-negative measurable function. Then there is a sequence of non-negative  simple functions $g_n$ increasing to $g$.

If $h=\sum c_i1_{A_i}$ is a simple function, then $\int hd \mu=\sum a_i \mu (A_i)$ and $\int h(-x) d\mu(x)=\int \sum c_i1_{-A_i}d\mu(x)=\sum c_i\mu(-A_i))=\sum c_i\mu(A_i))=\int h(x)d\mu(x).$

Thus, $\int g_n(x)d\mu(x)=\int g_n(-x)d\mu(x)$ for each $n$. Apllying Montone Convergence Theoerm we now get $$\int g(x)d\mu(x)=\int g(-x)d\mu(x)$$
The same equation holds for any measurable function for which the integrals exist (by writing $g$ as $g^{+}-g^{-}$).

Finally, if $g$ is an odd function we get $\int g(x)d\mu(x)=\int g(-x)d\mu(x)=-\int g(x)d\mu(x)$ so $\int g(x)d\mu(x)=0$.

Comment: So, can I say that if $d\mu(x) = f(x) dx$ where $f(x)$ is not odd, then $\int_Q \frac{x}{|x|^2} d\mu(x)\neq 0$? Can you provide a conuterexample? And if $\mu$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue, is there a chance that we have $\int_Q \frac{x}{|x|^2} d\mu(x)= 0$? Ok, you said that if $\mu(E)= \mu(-E)$, then it is ok. Could you risk some demonstration sketches? I think it's worth giving you this score. Thank you.

Comment: The integral is not $0$ when $f(x)=x+x^{2}$, for example.  @user346624

Comment: You definitely cannot prove that the integral is not $0$ whenever $f$ is not odd. [That is almost like saying that if $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx=0$ then $f$ must be an odd function!].  You  can construct easy counter-examples. @user346624

Comment: Dear, I am trying to show that $\int_Q  \frac{x}{||x||^2} d \mu(x)=0$. You said that if $\mu(-E)= \mu(E)$ for every Borel set $E$, we have $\int g(x)d \mu(x)=0$ for every odd function. In this case, I believe that the integration over $Q$ can be solved by doing $g(x)=\frac{x}{||x||^2} \mathbf{1}_{Q}$, right? Now, I want to formally demonstrate your claim. I thought about doing it first for function $g$ that are simple, but I don't know if it can work. Could you give me a tip?

Comment: To prove the result I have stated just make the change of variable $x \to -x$.  @user346624

Comment: @user346624 I have added a detailed proof of the result I had stated.